# Google Glass connecting to Arduino's HC-06 Bluetooth module

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, arduino, google-glass

I'm trying to establish a bluetooth connection between Google Glass and a HC-06 Bluetooth module connected to an Arduino Uno.

However while trying to run socket.connect() I'm getting the following exception: **java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1**

```
try {
     socket = remote_device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } catch (Exception e) {
                          }

    adapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // connect socket
    try {
        socket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,  e.toString());
    }
```

Has anyone an idea what is going wrong here? The mac-adress is hardcoded and the needed requirements are in the AndroidManifest as well.

Is this kind of bluetooth connection not possible at all on Google Glass?

Looking forward to your replies.

Thanks, 
Dominik

**Update: Complete code for connection which is then used in onCreate**

```
 public void connect() {


    BluetoothDevice remote_device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(mac_adresse);


    try {
        socket = remote_device
                .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    adapter.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        socket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    if (!is_connected) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    try {
        stream_out = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        is_connected = false;
    }

    // Inputstream erstellen
    try {
        stream_in = socket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        is_connected = false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show us the pairing code?

Comment: I attached some more code. It fails at command   "socket.connect();"